# UIGestureRecognizer on a rounded view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, rounded-corners, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView` and I use below code to make it round.

```
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[myView layer] setCornerRadius:[myView bounds].size.height / 2.0f];
[[myView layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
[myView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Then add  `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to move the box

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(boxIsMoving:)];
        [myView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

But the problem is when user tap outside of the round but in actual frame of and started dragging my view also start moving. Can anybody suggest me how could I ignore the touches outside of the round.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the actual distance from the center of your view to the point that is touched? If your view is really a circle, that should do the job, since the minimum distance is simply ahfl the height of your view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this delegate method. It will return NO if touch is outside of the corner radius.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    CGPoint  touchPoint = [touch locationInView:myView];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(myview.bounds, touchPoint))
    {
        CGFloat centerX = CGRectGetMidX(myView.bounds);
        CGFloat centerY = CGRectGetMidY(myView.bounds);
        CGFloat radius2 = pow((touchPoint.x -centerX),2)+ pow((touchPoint.y - centerY), 2);
        if (radius2 < pow(CGRectGetWidth(myView.frame)/2, 2))
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Erik Dolor suggested you can just calculate the distance between your gesture and the centre point of the view. Using something like this;

```
- (IBAction)boxIsMoving:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint viewCentre = CGPointMake(myView.bounds.size.width / 2, myView.bounds.size.height / 2);

    CGPoint gesturePosition = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

    float distanceGestureToViewCentre = abs((sqrt((viewCentre.x - gesturePosition.x) 
                                             * (viewCentre.x - gesturePosition.x)
                                             + (viewCentre.y - gesturePosition.y) 
                                             * (viewCentre.y - gesturePosition.y))));

    if(distanceTapToViewCentre < radiusOfView)
    {
        // Handle pan
    }
    else
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Utsav's answer below is probably better than mine!